# How to insert cell into UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm creating an iPad app. The root UITableview has a right bar button item in the navigation controller. When you tap the button, it shows a pop over controller. The popover is a UITableViewController. When you tap a cell in the popover, how could I pass the data in that cell and insert it into a cell into the root UITableview? I searched the Apple docs and couldn't find what I needed. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Roottable.h

```
@interface Roottable : UITableViewController<PopoverDelegate>
```

Popover.h

```
    @protocol AthleteSelectPopoverDelegate <NSObject>
    @required
    -(void)selectedObject:(Object *)newObject;
    @end


@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PopoverDelegate> delegate;


    @property (readwrite, nonatomic) Object *currentObject;

@end
```

popover.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _currentObject = [_objectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    //Notify the delegate if it exists.
    if (_delegate != nil) {
        [_delegate selectedObject:_currentObject];
    }
}
```

Comment: What result do you get with your current code? Does this statement run -- [_delegate selectedObject:_currentObject];? Have you logged it? How did the root table view controller set itself as the delegate of Popover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Hope I help someone. I'll explain the code first then post it below. Basically, I set the data source of the root table view, "ObjectSelect", as a `NSMutableArray` called "currentObjectArray". ObjectSelect is also the ObjectSelectPopoverDelegate. Basically, when a cell in the popover is tapped, it adds the object tapped to the "currentObjectArray" and reloads the tableview.

ObjectSelect.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ObjectSelectPopover.h"

@interface ObjectSelect : UITableViewController<ObjectSelectPopoverDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) ObjectSelectPopover *objectPicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *objectPickerPopover;

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) Object *currentObject;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedObjectArray;

@end
```

ObjectSelect.m

```
-(void)selectedObject:(Object *)newObject
    {
    _currentObject = newObject;

    if(!_selectedObjectArray){
    _selectedObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    if([_selectedObjectArray containsObject:_currentAthlete]){
        //lol you don't get added, bub
    }
    else{
    [_selectedObjectArray addObject:_currentObject];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        Object *objectTapped = (Object *)[_objectAthleteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }
```

ObjectSelectPopover.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Object.h"

@protocol ObjectSelectPopoverDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)selectedObject:(Object *)newObject;
@end

@interface ObjectSelectPopover : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ObjectSelectPopoverDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objectArray;

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) Object *currentObject;

@end
```

ObjectSelectPopover.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _currentObject = [_objectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Notify the delegate if it exists.
    if (_delegate != nil) {
        [_delegate selectedObject:_currentObject];
    }
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You add data from the selected cell to the main table's data source delegate.

Then that data source should tell the main table that a cell has been inserted at an index path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a property with a name other than `delegate` in your popover controller since `UITableViewController` already has a `delegate` property for the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol; maybe `masterTable` or something.

Then in the `selectedObject:` implementation in the root UITableView you can do an insert row or add it to the data array and `reload` the table.

Oops, my bad... @geraldWilliam is right, UITableViewController does not have the delegate property...

What you have seems like it should work... So does the **selectedObject:** method get called in the delegate? If so, what do you do in that method? If you add the object to the data set (array or dictionary or database) for the root view, insert a row in its tableview (or reload the data), it should work.

Here is some code that works for me. It is not from a popover but from a pushed view but there is no reason that should make a difference:

```
- (ThingStatus) thingPicker: (ThingPickerTableViewController *) thingPicker didSelectThing: (Thing *) thing {
    NSLog( @"Entering %s", __func__ );
    // Dismiss the pushed view controller (for you, the popover)
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    NSArray *startingList = self.currentCellObjectList;
    [self.databaseManager addThing: thing];
    NSArray *endingList = self.databaseManager.thingsForTableView;

    // Figure out the differences adding made...
    DiffResult *changes = [startingList simpleDiffWithArray: endingList];
    NSLog( @"%d deletions, %d insertions", changes.deletionCount, changes.insertionCount );
    // I only handle insertions in this code... deletions would be similar
    __block NSUInteger objIdx = 0;
    NSMutableArray *changeableThingList = [startingList mutableCopy];
    [changes.insertionIndexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock: ^( NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop ) {
        NSLog( @" - insert %@ at %d", [[changes.insertionObjects objectAtIndex: objIdx] name], idx );
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: idx inSection: 0];
        [changeableThingList insertObject: [changes.insertionObjects objectAtIndex: objIdx] atIndex: idx];
        self.currentCellObjectList = changeableThingList;
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        ++objIdx;
    }];
    [self.databaseManager save];
    return [self.databaseManager: thingStatus];
```

}

Comment: UITableView has a delegate property. UITableViewController does not.

Answer (score -2):

Here is some good code to use that may be able to help you.

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.item.count;
 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Get the row
    Sport *rowSport = self.sports[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = rowItem.itemName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = rowItem.section;

    return cell;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I know how to populate cells, I just don't know how to populate cells on the action when the popover cells are tapped.

Comment: Where is the data in the cells coming from?

Comment: from the delegate method, it is a single object, the object that was tapped in the popover.